# Why is there a value printed and not NULL/0 after incrementing a pointer in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers

I am fairly new to C++, so excuse if this is quite basic.

I am trying to understand the value printed after I increment my pointer in the following piece of code

```
int main() 
{
    int i = 5;
    int* pointeri = &i;
    cout << pointeri << "\n";
    pointeri++;
    i =7;
    cout << *pointeri << "\n";
}
```

When I deference the pointer, it prints a random Integer. I am trying to understand, what is really happening here, why isn't the pointer pointing at NULL and does the random integer have a significance  ?

Comment: That's because you really don't know what will happen to your program [when demons start flying out of your nose](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nasal_demon).

Comment: When behaviour is undefined, any output (or other behaviour) is possible.   Practically, you're treating some random location in memory (immediately after the location of `i`) as if it is an `int`, and printing whatever value is found there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C++ language has a concept of [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). It means that it is possible to write code that does not constitute a valid program, and the compiler won't stop or even warn you. What such code does when executed is unknown.

Your program is a typical example. After the line `int* pointeri = &i;`, the pointer is pointing to the value `i`. After `pointeri++` it is pointing to the memory location after the value `i`. What is stored at that location is unknown and the behavior of such code is undefined.

Needless to say, great care should be taken when coding in C++ in order to stay in the realm of *defined behavior*, in order to have meaningful and predictable results when running the program.

Comment: afaik "After pointeri++ it is pointing to the memory location after the value i" is already expecting something that is actually not defined, though the net result is the same

Comment: i might be wrong though, I remember something about pointers one-past being ok but not dereferencable

Comment: A pointer to a single value can be seen as a pointer to an array of one element. And indeed, dereferencing the past-the-end pointer is undefined behavior.

Comment: welll then, as expected, your answer is correct and mine needs a fix ;)

Comment: @idclev463035818 • pointing to the memory location after the value i is defined; dereferencing it is undefined.  You can use standard algorithms that take a begin/end range on a single item taking the address of the item and a pointer (that isn't dereferenced) after the item.

Comment: @Eljay thanks. I was always wondering what is the point of treating a single object as a single element array. Now it makes sense. Fwiw, my answer wasnt terribly wrong, but it missed the point, so I deleted it

Answer (score 2):

> why isn't the pointer pointing at NULL

Because you haven't assigned or initialised the pointer to null.

> and does the random integer have a significance ?

No.

> Why is there a value printed ...

Because the behaviour of the program is undefined.

Comment: My background is Java, that's why I had the assumption it would be NULL

Comment: @AhmedAbdulkareem There is no pointer arithmetic in Java as far as I know. It is unclear what behaviour in Java you were basing your assumption on. Regardless, it is not wise to assume behaviour based on an unrelated language.

Comment: @eerorika There's no pointer arithmetic, but pointing to an empty or unused memory cell would through a Null pointer exception

Comment: @Peter I understand that now. thank you for the clarification

Comment: @AhmedAbdulkareem As far as I know, it is not possible to point to an "empty" or "unused memory cell" in Java (my knowledge of Java is almost 10 year old though).

Comment: Iterating over uninitialized Object collections, for example is what I mean

Answer (score 0):

As you know, a "pointer" is simply an integer variable whose value is understood to be a memory address.  If that value is *zero,* by convention we call it `NULL` and understand this to mean that "it doesn't point at anything."  Otherwise, the value is presumed to be valid.

If you "increment" a pointer, its value is non-zero and therefore presumed to be valid.  If you dereference it, you will either get "unpredictable data" or a memory-addressing fault.